# Use a variable as a key while pushing a dictionary to a list

Tags: reactjs

I have this:

```
var x = [];

y.map(({ myVariable }) =>
x.push({
      myVariable: false
    })
);
```

How can I use **myVariable** as the key based on my data in **y**?

Something like **{myVariable}: false** is not working

Comment: `{[myVariable]:false}`

Comment: Hi @bbbbbbbboat:   Line 478:6:  Parsing error: Property assignment expected. Soorry, you are right. It was (according to my example): [division_head]: false. Thank you!